# Screw not fully screwed into drywall anchor

Tags: drywall, mounting, anchor

I used [these](http://www.products.marcopol.eu/katalog/zamocow-do-plyt-gips/kolek-do-pustych-przestrzeni/2/group_20) drywall anchors. They went into the wall just fine and are flush against the wall. However my clothing rack requires 16 screws, and I think I didn't measure and drill perfectly well, so for some of the anchors, the screw didn't go into the very center if the anchor. So now, some screws aren't totally flush and can't be screwed in all the way (when I try with a screwdriver, the turn I did get undid as soon I stop). They're missing a few turns, they're mostly screwed in.

Is this catastrophic? am I just waiting for the rack and everything to fall down?

Comment: How many of the 16 anchor/screw sets *did* seem to anchor and set properly?

Comment: A photo would also be helpful but if all but a couple are good I doubt I would be two concerned unless you pack it tight with heavy clothes.